# business catalyst unable to output webapp description with liquid

Tags: liquid, business-catalyst

I am using liquid to cycle through all the items of a webapp and output the various fields.  This works fine but for some reason I cannot output the description field.

The following code is a simplified version of what I am using:

```
{module_webapps id="26025" collection="tutors" filter="all" template=""}

{% for tutor in tutors.items %}
  {{tutor}}
  {{tutor.name}}
  {{tutor.description}}
  {{tutor.["external website"]}}
{% endfor -%}
```

The `{{tutor}}` tag outputs an array of all the fields for the current web app item *except* the description, so I guess it is unsurprising that `{{tutor.description}}` also does not work.  Why is this?

When using the template layout (which I don't want to do) `{tag_description}` and {{description}} work as expected.

Does anyone know how can I access the description field when using liquid in this way outside of a template layout?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's currently an issue with the `description` field and fields of type `Image` - they aren't made available for use unless there is some Liquid markup in the standard list template file (at `/Layouts/Webapps/WEBAPPNAME/list.html`). 
Adding a comment such as this should resolve it:

```
{% comment %} This is to get the description and image fields to work {% endcomment %}
```

This issue is being discussed on the official Adobe Business Catalyst forums: https://forums.adobe.com/ideas/4133

Comment: Great, thanks!  It is important to note that this fixes the issue even when using in-line collections (as I am here) which do not even reference the default templates.  *Crazy* bug.